# Rewrite rule to remove any appearance of given utf-8 charachter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, right-to-left

In our system we send hebrew (RTL) message that contains link (which is LTR). In a strange way - some devices (Galaxy note 4 models: SM-N910F and SM-N910C) add extra characters at the end of the link. And instead showing this:

```
example.com/abc
```

It indeed shows this link in sms, but when pressing the link it goes to:

```
example.com/abc%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E
```

I couldn't do anything to cause these devices to not adding these charachters. So, because the link points to our server, my last solution is to add RewriteRule to .htaccess file in order to forward any url contains %E2%80%8F or %E2%80%8E characters to the same url but when these two character is removed.

For example, I want to rewrite [example.com/aaa%E2%80%8Fbbb%E2%80%8Eccc](http://example.com/aaa%E2%80%8Fbbb%E2%80%8Eccc) to [example.com/aaabbbccc](http://example.com/aaabbbccc)

BTW, these characters are RTL/LTR marks and their unicode id is U+200F=%E2%80%8F and U+200E=%E2%80%8E. [See more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) on Wikipedia.

Comment: You want to handle this with CSS shims and not try to do this in htaccess code, which will not work anyway:  https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ +/([^\ \?]*)(?:%E2|%80|%8F)+([^\ \?]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rewrite rules that you already have in there.

Comment: I got '500 Internal Server Error'. did you miss something?

Comment: @uriel sorry, forgot to escape those spaces. See edit. Also you may need `RewriteEngine On` if you don't already have it.

Comment: It's now seems like it catches "%E2%80%8F" and "%E2%80%8E". But it forwards http://example.com/abc%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E to http://example.com/abc%25E2%2580%258F%25E2%258E instead of http://example.com/abc